# Maven release does not work with a grouping pom

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I want to release a project with the following structre (simplified):

parent
--module A (packaging type: pom)

--module B (type jar)

--module C (type jar, uses A and B as dependency)

I want to release my project with the help of Jenkins. A build works fine.
But for the release it seems that there will not be a version of the pom-typed project in the reactor. The build failed because no version of the pom-type project can be found in my maven repository. With the dependency of type jar everything works well.

Can anybody help me?

here you can see the console out out and my test pom-files:

```
    [INFO] [release:prepare {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /CVS1/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/PomDepstest/workspace && git status
[INFO] Working directory: /CVS1/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/PomDepstest/workspace
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
[INFO] Transforming 'Unnamed - com.basfits.test:parentTest:pom:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT'...
[INFO] Transforming 'Unnamed - com.basfits.test:childTestSimplePom:pom:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT'...
[INFO] Transforming 'Unnamed - com.basfits.test:testjarDep:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT'...
[INFO] Transforming 'Unnamed - com.basfits.test:testPomDep:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT'...
[INFO] Updating testjarDep to 0.0.2
[INFO] Updating childTestSimplePom to 0.0.2
[INFO] Not generating release POMs
[INFO] Executing goals 'clean verify'...
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [INFO] Reactor build order: 
[INFO] [INFO]   Unnamed - com.basfits.test:parentTest:pom:0.0.2
[INFO] [INFO]   Unnamed - com.basfits.test:childTestSimplePom:pom:0.0.2
[INFO] [INFO]   Unnamed - com.basfits.test:testjarDep:jar:0.0.2
[INFO] [INFO]   Unnamed - com.basfits.test:testPomDep:jar:0.0.2
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building Unnamed - com.basfits.test:parentTest:pom:0.0.2
[INFO] [INFO]    task-segment: [clean, verify]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] [INFO] [site:attach-descriptor {execution: default-attach-descriptor}]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building Unnamed - com.basfits.test:childTestSimplePom:pom:0.0.2
[INFO] [INFO]    task-segment: [clean, verify]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] [INFO] [site:attach-descriptor {execution: default-attach-descriptor}]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building Unnamed - com.basfits.test:testjarDep:jar:0.0.2
[INFO] [INFO]    task-segment: [clean, verify]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] [INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /CVS1/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/PomDepstest/workspace/testjarDep/src/main/resources
[INFO] [INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /CVS1/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/PomDepstest/workspace/testjarDep/target/classes
[INFO] [INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[INFO] [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /CVS1/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/PomDepstest/workspace/testjarDep/src/test/resources
[INFO] [INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] [INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] [INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] [INFO] [jar:jar {execution: default-jar}]
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: /CVS1/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/PomDepstest/workspace/testjarDep/target/testjarDep-0.0.2.jar
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building Unnamed - com.basfits.test:testPomDep:jar:0.0.2
[INFO] [INFO]    task-segment: [clean, verify]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] [INFO] Deleting directory /CVS1/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/PomDepstest/workspace/testPomDep/target
[INFO] [INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /CVS1/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/PomDepstest/workspace/testPomDep/src/main/resources
[INFO] Downloading: http://maven.bcs.de/content/repositories/bis-releases/com/basfits/test/childTestSimplePom/0.0.2/childTestSimplePom-0.0.2.pom
[INFO] [INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.basfits.test:childTestSimplePom:pom:0.0.2' in repository bis-releases (http://maven.bcs.de/content/repositories/bis-releases)
[INFO] Downloading: http://maven.bcs.de/content/groups/public/com/basfits/test/childTestSimplePom/0.0.2/childTestSimplePom-0.0.2.pom
[INFO] [INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.basfits.test:childTestSimplePom:pom:0.0.2' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Missing:
[INFO] ----------
[INFO] 1) com.basfits.test:childTestSimplePom:pom:0.0.2
[INFO]   Path to dependency: 
[INFO]      1) com.basfits.test:testPomDep:jar:0.0.2
[INFO]      2) com.basfits.test:childTestSimplePom:pom:0.0.2
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------
[INFO] 1 required artifact is missing.
[INFO] 
[INFO] for artifact: 
[INFO]   com.basfits.test:testPomDep:jar:0.0.2
[INFO] 
[INFO] from the specified remote repositories:
[INFO]   nexus-central (http://maven.bcs.de/content/groups/public),
[INFO]   bis-releases (http://maven.bcs.de/content/repositories/bis-releases),
[INFO]   bis-snapshots (http://maven.bcs.de/content/repositories/bis-snapshots)
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 08 13:43:48 CEST 2012
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 21M/271M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /CVS1/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/PomDepstest/workspace/pom.xml to /CVS1/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/PomDepstest/modules/com.basfits.test$parentTest/builds/2012-06-08_13-43-09/archive/com.basfits.test/parentTest/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/parentTest-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
```

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.basfits.test</groupId>
<artifactId>parentTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<build />
<scm>
    <connection>...</connection>
    <url>...</url>
    </scm>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>bis-releases</id>
        <name>BIS Releases</name>
        <url>...</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>bis-snapshots</id>
        <name>BIS Snapshots</name>
        <url>...</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
<modules>
    <module>childTestSimplePom</module>
    <module>testPomDep</module>
    <module>testjarDep</module>
</modules>
```

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parentTest</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.basfits.test</groupId>
        <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>childTestSimplePom</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <build />


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>parentTest</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.basfits.test</groupId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>testPomDep</artifactId>
  <build />

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>testjarDep</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>       
        <groupId>com.basfits.test</groupId>     
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <artifactId>childTestSimplePom</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>       
        <groupId>com.basfits.test</groupId>     
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: you should mark @Wim Deblauwe's answer as the accepted one so he gets his cue credit.

Answer (score 11):

You can set the preparation goals to `clean install` (default is `clean verify`). Add this in your grouping pom:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    <plugins>
<build>
```

This will install the released pom.xml into your local repository so your submodules can find it.